# Synology SSL & nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, synology

I have a synology NAS where I have a let's encrypt certificate installed. From the outside I can browse to https://mynas.dyndns.info and I will receive a secure page. So this i working fine!

Now I am trying to run a nodejs server on port 3000. How can I get this connection secure? I have no idea where to begin. Any tips tutorial's, examples?

Thanks in advance,

Peter

Comment: can you not make a reverse proxy and redirect traffic to your node app? like `https://mynas.dyndns.info/nodeApp` will go to localhost:300

Comment: COOL! That works! Thanks a lot for triggering me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably make a reverse proxy in this case.

For **nginx** I use this basic configuration for my node apps:

```
server {

    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /actions {
        rewrite ^/actions$ / break;
        rewrite ^/actions/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
    }
}
```

And For **apache** serving as a web server I

> 1. Create a folder in www or public_html, let's say `node`
> 2. Inside node I make a `.htaccess` file and
> 3. add the following lines,
>
>    ```
>    RewriteEngine On
>    RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:8080/ [P,L] #which is your node server ip:port
>    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8080/$1 [P,L] #same ip:port
>    ```